# Asking a user multiple questions using Ruby gets.chomp method

Tags: ruby

I'm very new to Ruby and practicing with user input. I have coded the following which allows the user to input names of students continuously until they hit return twice. After each input the program returns how many students are in the school, and when they are finished inputting for good, it prints out a list of the students and the cohort they are in.

At the moment, the cohort is hardcoded, and I want to modify this so that I can ask for both the name and the cohort, with the program continuing to ask for this info until the user hits return twice. Any help would really be appreciated - thanks :)

```
  puts "Please enter the names of the students"
  puts "To finish, just hit return twice"

  students = []

  name = gets.chomp

  while !name.empty? do 
    students << {name: name, cohort: cohort} 
    puts "Now we have #{students.count} students" 
    name = gets.chomp
  end
  students
end

def print_header
  puts "The students of this Academy".center(50)
  puts "-----------".center(50)
end

def print(students)
 students.each do |student, index|
   puts "#{student[:name]} #{student[:cohort]} cohort"
    end
 end
end

def print_footer(names)
  puts "Overall, we have #{names.count} great students".center(50)
end

students = input_students
print_header
print(students)
print_footer(students)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a [while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop) loop, I'd suggest to use [loop do](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and [break](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) in case the `name` is empty (or also `cohort`):

```
loop do 
  puts "Please enter the names of the students"
  name = gets.chomp
  break if name.empty?
  puts "Please enter the cohort"
  cohort = gets.chomp
  # break if cohort.empty?
  students << {name: name, cohort: cohort} 
end
```